# Can I delete data from two tables by join condition in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my code.

```
DELETE tbemp.emp_id, 
        tbadd.emp_id 
FROM  TBEMPLOYEE tbemp 
INNER JOIN TBADDRESS tbadd ON (tbemp.emp_id=tbadd.emp_id)
```

it is not working. SQL Server 2008 R2 does not run it

Comment: In SQL `DELETE` always operates on a single table. You need to use two `DELETE`s, or set up your `TBADDRESS` with a foreign key to `TBEMPLOYEE`, and use the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should work, take a safe try,

```
DELETE TBEMPLOYEE FROM 
TBEMPLOYEE INNER JOIN 
TBADDRESS ON (TBEMPLOYEE.emp_id = TBADDRESS.emp_id)
```

You can also specify where condition here,

```
WHERE COL IN ('A','B',...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using columns name(DELETE tbemp.emp_id, tbadd.emp_id) in place of table name and suggested by others , Delete works on a single table only.

Hope this work for you -

```
DELETE TBEMPLOYEE FROM 
TBEMPLOYEE INNER JOIN 
TBADDRESS ON (TBEMPLOYEE.emp_id = TBADDRESS.emp_id)

DELETE TBADDRESS FROM 
TBEMPLOYEE Right JOIN 
TBADDRESS ON (TBEMPLOYEE.emp_id = TBADDRESS.emp_id)
```

Execute in a same order.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Tbl table ( emp_id int)

DELETE from tbemp
output deleted.emp_id into @t

FROM  TBEMPLOYEE tbemp 
JOIN TBADDRESS tbadd ON tbemp.emp_id=tbadd.emp_id

DELETE from tbadd

FROM TBADDRESS tbadd 
join @T T ON T.emp_id=tbadd.emp_id
```